# Why doesn't XPages mask my input?

Tags: input, dojo, xpages, masking

I'm trying to get my input field to mask user input, like this: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

However the underlying code doesn't seem to do anything. I can still input whatever I want.

```
<xp:inputText id="Mask"> 
  <xp:this.converter> 
    <xp:convertMask mask="####-####-####-####" asis="true"></xp:convertMask> 
  </xp:this.converter> 
  <xp:this.validators> 
    <xp:validateConstraint> 
      <xp:this.regex><![CDATA[[0-9]{16}]]></xp:this.regex> 
    </xp:validateConstraint> 
  </xp:this.validators> 
</xp:inputText>
```

I'm not getting any errors from XPages of the browser.
Trying it with djTextBox gives the same result.

What am I doing wrong? Please let me know if I should add more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an error message(s) control to your XPage. The converter/validator works on server side.

The error message(s) control will show you validation errors after round trip to server.